# Can any one explain me the complete Sabre Air booking flow after we get the results from search

Tags: soap, sabre

Please find the below response which i get while calling the book in soap

```
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
               <soap-env:Header>
                  <eb:MessageHeader eb:version="1.0" soap-env:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader">
                     <eb:From>
                        <eb:PartyId eb:type="URI">Sabre</eb:PartyId>
                     </eb:From>
                     <eb:To>
                        <eb:PartyId eb:type="URI">Traform</eb:PartyId>
                     </eb:To>
                     <eb:CPAId>VJ6I</eb:CPAId>
                     <eb:ConversationId>TraformConversationId</eb:ConversationId>
                     <eb:Service eb:type="OTA">OTA_AirBookRQ</eb:Service>
                     <eb:Action>ErrorRS</eb:Action>
                     <eb:MessageData>
                        <eb:MessageId>2851813190937520610</eb:MessageId>
                        <eb:Timestamp>2017-05-18T05:18:13</eb:Timestamp>
                        <eb:RefToMessageId>TraformMessage</eb:RefToMessageId>
                     </eb:MessageData>
                  </eb:MessageHeader>
                  <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
                     <wsse:BinarySecurityToken valueType="String" EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary">T1RLAQJjFvduEm77D3CMjwxPjYk6gM1h1hByCnRdGipBRXTeqMsCcruqAACwOycU0Ymu010+D+Zc4NZNAVrusbm2wnNtL9eR8rbRZQqrb+HGaWtR/lFTOfm9ycPWkiZjyJi2AyaDn45OKyheGfdu5a0Nt+B4U5Ni07YJhLy+F5YNBfQEsP20ETKOYj2vRvWoS+U28A8lwtfpRaBI5GRkHQxnwebWIvPusHxCt7PxYDZ6P1x1vcMnPsefuxjJiHsPnXwL+YTi87sjTDp6vEwJKMb91I3/gnUtfGr17VE*</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
                  </wsse:Security>
               </soap-env:Header>
               <soap-env:Body>
                  <soap-env:Fault>
                     <faultcode>soap-env:Client.AuthorizationFailed</faultcode>
                     <faultstring>Authorization failed</faultstring>
                     <detail>
                        <StackTrace>com.sabre.universalservices.base.security.AuthorizationException: errors.authorization.USG_AUTHORIZATION_FAILED</StackTrace>
                     </detail>
                  </soap-env:Fault>
               </soap-env:Body>
            </soap-env:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple flow comes down to at least (I ommit transactions which may be required for your specific client):

```
 - CreateSessionRQ - which opens new session on which you'll be working on. Also, you'll get secuity token, which you should put in every following request
 - AirBookRQ - in which you provide specific details of selected flight (tlcs, dates, booking classes, etc). This transactions update session you created in CreateSessionRQ.
 - AirPriceRQ - This is used in order to get price details for selected itinerary (and must be invoked AFTER the AirBookRQ)

 **Both AirBookRQ and AirPriceRQ** can be passed to Sabre in one XML in transaction which is called EnhancedAirBookRQ

 - PassengerDetailsRQ - which groups several different transactions and aims to update reservation with all passenger details (names, date of birth, bought extra services, meals). Don't forget to include EndTransactionRQ in this request - otherwise passed data won't be saved in PNR
 - AirTicketRQ - which is used for tickets issueing
```

This is just a very simple overview - my expierience tells me that you may encounter some issues during the integration, because additional transactions may be required for your specific client/flow, but it should be a bit easier now for you.

Comment: Hi djaszczurowski,
I Perform a search using a rest API https://api.test.sabre.com/InstaFlights Search
  
  I  received search results with price and   i want to book a specific flight  which i received from the above rest call ,then i performed the below 
SessionCreateRQ (to create a session token) got the session token 
EnhancedAirBookRQ (this contains 2 part OTA_AirBookRQ and OTA_AirPriceRQ) can i omit OTA_AirPriceRQ since i already know the price and go for PassengerDetailsRQ and then AirTicketRQ   ? Please advice

Comment: no, you can't because OTA_AirPriceRq is required in order to store pricing details in AAA (`Retain="true"`  flag in PriceRequestInformation node -
 browse https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/air/book/price_air_itinerary)

Answer (score 0):

There are some simple workflows defined in Sabre DevStudio:

https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/workflows/Low_Fare_Search_and_Book

https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/workflows/Book_Air_Segment

Regarding the actual error that you're getting. I believe it is due to using a sessionless token with a service that doesn't allow it. You should use SessionCreateRQ to request the BST.